# How to centre the characters in a looped output?

Tags: c, formatting

I am looking to print in the pattern of Pascal's triangle, but ran into difficulties here. Haven't found a solution yet, as most of the solutions I'm finding only explain how to print the pattern (without appropriately formatting the output, ie just a triangle as opposed to the pyramid shape).

```
int pascal(int length)
{
    int row=1,col;
    while(row<=length)
    {
        col=0;
        while(col<row)
        {
             printf(" ");
             printf("*");
             col++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        row++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("How many rows in the triangle? ");
    /* Rows = Columns. This is just the size of the triangle. */
    scanf("%d",&x),
    pascal(x);
    return(0);
}
```

This is the current output

```
How many rows in the triangle?
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

...and this is what I'm looking for

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

Comment: 4 rows will result in 2*4-1 columns.  Use that in setting up your loop index, and deciding where to put your spaces.

Comment: This is clearly an assignment, you should do it by yourself. What you need to is figure out, where and how many spaces you need to print. You're almost there though.

Comment: There should be a `return` statement in `pascal()`.  And your post has been edited already, but don't forget to use proper formatting, including indentation for readability.

Comment: Please do not add screenshots to show us plain text.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
int main()
{
    int row,mid,tab,temp,num;
    printf("Enter no of Rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&row);

    tab=row-1;

    int arr1[MAX],arr2[MAX];

    for (int i=1;i<=row;i++,tab--)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\t");
        temp=tab;

        arr1[0]=1; arr1[i-1]=1;

        for(;temp>=1;temp--)
            printf("  ");

        if (i==1)
            printf("1  ");

        else
        {
            arr2[0]=1; arr2[i]=1;
            int l=0,m=1;
            for (int j=1;j<i;j++)
            {

                arr2[j]=arr1[l]+arr1[m];
                l++,m++;
            }

            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(j==0)
                        printf("%d  ",arr1[j]);
                    else
                        printf(" %d  ",arr1[j]);
                }
            for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
                arr1[j]=arr2[j];
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}

Go through this carefully. Comment if you have problems understanding it.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out how many spaces to add before starting the characters for each row. The bottom row needs 0 spaces, and each row should have 1 space less than the row above. So, starting from the top, you need `length` spaces, `length - 1` for the next row, `length - 2` for the third, and so on. Simple enough to implement:

```
int pascal(int length)
{
    int row=1,col;
    while(row<=length)
    {
        col=0;
        for( int i = 0; i < length - row; i++ ){
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(col<row)
        {
             printf(" ");
             printf("*");
             col++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        row++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("How many rows in the triangle? ");
    /* Rows = Columns. This is just the size of the triangle. */
    scanf("%d",&x),
    pascal(x);
    return(0);
}
```

This produces the correct output for me:

```
$ ./triangle
How many rows in the triangle? 6
      *
     * *
    * * *
   * * * *
  * * * * *
 * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int row,col,space,number,n;
        printf("Enter How many row you can print ? = ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        for(row = 0; row<number; row++)
        {
            for(space = 0; space<number - row ; space++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            n=1;
            for(col = 0; col<=row; col++)
            {
                printf(" %d", n);
                n = n * (row - col)/(col+1);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Output is :

```
Enter How many row you can print ? = 5

        1
       1 1
      1 2 1
     1 3 3 1
    1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: Just giving the code doesn't make a good answer. It will be good to add some explanation.